# android duplicating one dynamic child view in listview on action mode copy click

Tags: android, listview, duplicate-data

In listview, i am looking to create an action(eg. COPY) that will duplicate a selected view (with a new ID) in a list of objects. The view must be created next to the selected view. Any idea?

Here is my adapter

public class Test extends BaseAdapter {

```
Context context;
ArrayList<ListItemVO> itemList;
List<String> editList;

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public EditText editText;
    public ViewSwitcher vs;
}

public Test(Context context, ArrayList<ListItemVO> arr) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemList = arr;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return itemList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return itemList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView111);

        holder.editText = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.editText111);
        holder.vs = (ViewSwitcher) rowView.findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher111);

        rowView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
    holder.editText.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());

    holder.editText.setTag(R.id.TAG_POSITION_ID, position);
    holder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                final int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag(R.id.TAG_POSITION_ID).toString());
                final EditText editText = (EditText) v;
                String val = editText.getText().toString(); // you have the value here

                if (val.compareTo("") != 0) {
                    itemList.get(position).setName(val);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    holder.vs.setDisplayedChild(0);
    if(itemList.get(position).isEdit()) {
        holder.vs.setDisplayedChild(1);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

}

Comment: by on click created a copy of selected object values and added it adapter list and make adapter notifydatasetchanged. Any android api is available to do so?

Comment: sounds good. What's wrong?

Comment: Need to know android supporting any api like clone view with values with different id. And if it has edittext performance getting slow. :(

Comment: Please google thoroughly. There are many answers available for everything there is

Answer (score 0):

implement adapters `onItemClick()` for the adapter and update your list of items

For delete, remove that item from list.
For add, add an item at that position.
For edit, edit list.

in the end call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Thanks @BlackBeard. Done the same. Struggling with 6 edittext in a list item.

Comment: Using single edittext for sample, but in realtime i have to show 8 edittexts in a single row item.